# Problem loading .hdf5 model (ValueError: Unknown layer: FixedBatchNormalization)

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to convert .hdf5 model to .pb model. I'm stuck with loading the model.

Here is my code:

```py
import keras
keras.models.load_model('./model_frcnn.hdf5')
```

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qendrim/solaborate/repos/solaborate/Solaborate.ML/scripts/solaborate_scripts/practice.py", line 2, in <module>
    keras.models.load_model('./model_frcnn.hdf5')
  File "/home/qendrim/anaconda3/envs/hello-ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/home/qendrim/anaconda3/envs/hello-ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 225, in _deserialize_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/qendrim/anaconda3/envs/hello-ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 458, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/qendrim/anaconda3/envs/hello-ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/qendrim/anaconda3/envs/hello-ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/qendrim/anaconda3/envs/hello-ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1022, in from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/home/qendrim/anaconda3/envs/hello-ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1008, in process_layer
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/qendrim/anaconda3/envs/hello-ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/qendrim/anaconda3/envs/hello-ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 138, in deserialize_keras_object
    ': ' + class_name)
ValueError: Unknown layer: FixedBatchNormalization
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well... Keras does not have a `FixedBatchNormalization` layer. So it cannot load this layer.

If you know the code of this layer, pass it to `custom_objects={'FixedBatchNormalization' : FixedBatchNormalization}` parameter in `load_model`.

Comment: I assume that FixedBatchNormalization corresponds to keras.layers.BatchNormalization.
Now I have the next problem, and I can't find it's corresponding layer:

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: RoiPoolingConv
```

Any idea?

Comment: Another custom layer, you need the code for all custom layers. Unfortunately Keras will not be able to load custom layers without their custom codes.

Comment: @DanielMöller Can you please take a look into this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58900947/5904928
I am struggling for hours, couldn't find an answer.